# CKEditor use forcePasteAsPlainText unless copied from CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor and am setting

```
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
```

so I don't get any goofy formatting coming in from the outside. However, I would like to be able to copy and paste from the same (or other) CKEditor instances and retain the formatting. How do I go about doing that? I didn't see any settings like that. Is it possible?

Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Afaik the plugin is restrictive and limits pasted text no matter where it's from. This makes sense, because you cannot determine the origin of the content of the clipboard, can you? You only way to do this is to create a custom button/command to duplicate the selected text.

Answer (score 1):

@Smamatti is right. That would not be possible to determine the origin of the content. However, if you have the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) configured correctly (e.g. left to defaults), then CKEditor will limit data pasted from all sources to the features which are enabled in its configuration.

Comment: There is no way to trick it? Could I, when someone copies text in CKEditor, insert a tag at the beginning. Then when it's pasted I could check to see if it has that tag? If it does then remove it and paste the formatted code, otherwise paste the cleaned text? Sounds kind of nasty though. Might just have to deal with plain text.

Comment: To be able to modify copied data you would have to implement the idea of "copybin" - a hidden element to which selection is moved when user presses `ctrl+c`. I'm not sure whether you really want to start so tricky things ;). BTW. why do you want to limit pasting from other sources so much?

Comment: The app will be used by a large number of people and the formatting they are allowed to use is limited. Ultimately the content will be part of a printed book. So, if someone were to copy and paste text in with 11pt font (for example) when it should only be 10pt, it would cause a lot of trouble down the road.

Comment: Then use ACF and remove font dropdowns. User won't be able to change size of text and pasted text will be normalized.